# Shadow catcher doesn't work with multiple objects

Tags: shadowcatcher

I have multiple objects and I want to set all of them to `shadow catcher`. I want to render only the shadows that the objects cast on each other.

It works in the viewport shading render (cycles), but when I render, the output is empty.

I think there are some bugs, for examples:

- if I switch to viewport shading preview and then I switch back to viewport shading render, the shadows disappear also from the this viewport
- if i move an object in the viewport shading render the shadows disappears in this viewport
- if I save and then reopen the .blend file, the shadows disappear from the viewport shading render

Edit:

I noticed that in Blender *2.83.20* and in *2.93.20* there aren't these problems because shadow catcher seems to work in a slightly different way. In fact a shadow catcher objects doesn't cast shadows on another shadow catcher object.

The problems I highlighted appears on versions: *3.0.0*, *3.0.1*, *3.1.0*, *3.1.1*, *3.1.2* and *3.2.0*.

Edit 2:
[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16QGSiud2T4SRbDxPrSY1ZkfG0SyXARl9/view?usp=sharing) an example of the scene I'm using with Blender 3.1.0

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137294/discussion-on-question-by-dome-shadow-catcher-doesnt-work-with-multiple-objects).

Comment: Shadow Catcher object should not cast shadows ... so render is correct for me ... and reported should be SC casting shadow in viewport as a bug.